# MySQL order by two varchar columns

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble coming up with a descriptive title, so I think a better way to express what I want is with an example. Let's say I have a table with the following:

```
NAME | EMAIL
John | john@example.com
Mike | mike@example.com
NULL | albert@example.com
Bill | zebra_bill@example.com
```

I want to order the query so that the result will be:

```
NAME | EMAIL
NULL | albert@example.com
Bill | zebra_nill@example.com
John | john@example.com
Mike | mike@example.com
```

If it's not clear, it should be ordered by both name and email, mixing both priorities when the NAME column has no entry for that row. So if NAME is NULL, it uses the value in EMAIL to sort that row with respect to the other rows, but if NAME is not NULL, then it uses NAME and not EMAIL to sort.

As you can guess, `ORDER BY name ASC, email ASC` does not do the trick. I'm not really sure how to Google this, so I turn to SO. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   yourtable 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN name IS NULL THEN email 
            ELSE name 
          end, 
          email
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f48ec/2

Comment: There were a number of answers, but this is the first one I saw that matched up with what I ended up doing (I had a join and some more logic to add, but yeah).

Comment: Well, other people did not read carefully :), based on your example most answers assumed that all NULLs go on top, but you were clear that is not what you need.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to add a column to sort by:

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    EMAIL,
    IFNULL(NAME, EMAIL) AS sort_column
FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY
    sort_column
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT* FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY CASE WHEN NAME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, NAME, EMAIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, email
from my_table
ORDER BY name IS NULL DESC, NAME ASC, EMAIL ASC
```

Comment: hi, could you please explain me why using that `IS NULL` condition necessary? won't we get the same result with just `NAME` and `EMAIL` in `order by`?

Comment: @MridulKashyap  If you don'u use is  null for firts order the null value are place at the end .. the sintax mean firts the null  then the others

Comment: "When doing an ORDER BY, NULL values are presented first if you do ORDER BY ... ASC and last if you do ORDER BY ... DESC." Please check this [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html). since we need the names and email in ascending order, would it really be required to put "IS NULL"?

Comment: @MridulKashyap   i'm answer ad a question that require  that null the value null in column name are firts .. i don't understand your comment  .. since seems you are not the OP .. and ii don't understand if youe question is related to this .. so if you have a  specific question post it separately

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Name]
      ,[email]
  FROM [db1].[dbo].[emailTB] order by 
    CASE WHEN Name !='NULL'  THEN [Name] else NULL  end ,email
```

It worked for me!